# WebGL error when attempting to get color data from vec4

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

I'm having an issue while rendering a square in WebGL. When I run the program in Chrome, I'm getting the error:

```
GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0
```

I've assumed this is because, at some point, the buffers are looking at the wrong arrays when trying to get data. I've pinpointed the issue to the

```
gl.vertexAttribPointer(pColorIndex, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

line in the code below. i.e. if I change the 4 to a 2, the code will run, but not properly (as I'm looking at a vec4 for color data here). Is there an issue with the way my arrays are bound?

```
    bindColorDisplayShaders();
// clear the framebuffer
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// bind the shader
gl.useProgram(shader);

// set the value of the uniform variable in the shader
var shift_loc = gl.getUniformLocation(shader, "shift");
gl.uniform1f(shift_loc, .5);

// bind the buffer
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

// get the index for the a_Position attribute defined in the vertex shader
var positionIndex = gl.getAttribLocation(shader, 'a_Position');
if (positionIndex < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
    return;
}

// "enable" the a_position attribute
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex);

// associate the data in the currently bound buffer with the a_position attribute
// (The '2' specifies there are 2 floats per vertex in the buffer.  Don't worry about
// the last three args just yet.)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionIndex, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

// bind the buffer with the color data
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, chosencolorbuffer);

var pColorIndex = gl.getUniformLocation(shader, 'a_ChosenColor');
if(pColorIndex < 0){
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_ChosenColor');
}

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(pColorIndex);

gl.vertexAttribPointer(pColorIndex, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

// draw, specifying the type of primitive to assemble from the vertices
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numPoints);
```

Comment: Looks fine, does the  length of your colorbuffer match the amount of vertices in your position buffer?

Comment: @LJ there's only one color in the color buffer (which would be 4 floats), while theres a few vertices in the position buffer. This wouldn't be a problem though, would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use either a `uniform` **or** a `vertex attribute`,
this are two different things.

When using a ***vertex attribute*** you have to match the amount of vertices in your position buffer, and get the location using `gl.getAttribLocation`.

When using a ***uniform*** you're not supplying its data via array buffers but using the `gl.uniform*` methods to set their value.

In your example `gl.uniform4fv(pColorIndex, yourColorVector)`.

Comment: Oh, I see what I've done wrong now. I didn't notice this before, thanks!